# Using QGIS and PostGIS for multi-user capabilities, similar to ArcSDE for ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, open-source-gis, editing, free-software

I have previously used ArcSDE technology with Microsoft SQL Server to allow for multi-user database editing.

My ESRI licenses have recently ran out and I have been using QGIS for my GIS work.
I am now thinking of using QGIS to create a database on Postgres/PostGIS so I can give multiple people in my department the capability to edit and create GIS data on the same database. I am hoping to use only free and open source software for this and was wondering if I would need a server as well to fulfil these requirements?

Comment: So what do you actually asking about? Yes you can create multi-user database in PosGIS and edit it from within QGIS (you will provide user name and password when you will connect your DB). Ofcourse you will need one of the computers to serve as a server.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/user-manag.html will help get you started.

Comment: The trouble, I guess, is how to handle concurrent edits with locking etc. which is not so trivial.

Comment: are you concerned with users editing the same data record? if not, PostgreSQL/PostGIS can handle multiple users beautifully, including having multiple adds/deletes. you can set up tracking history as well so you can know who did what/when and be able to roll back to a point in time. it's not true versioning, but plenty functional, depending on your needs

Answer (score 1):

Boundless has a tool called GeoGig: http://geogig.org/

> Users are able to import raw geospatial data (currently from
>   Shapefiles, PostGIS or SpatiaLite) in to a repository where every
>   change to the data is tracked. These changes can be viewed in a
>   history, reverted to older versions, branched in to sandboxed areas,
>   merged back in, and pushed to remote repositories.